# Mule custom library using java class throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft, mule4

I have developed a custom mule library to verify and generate jwt token using java module. I imported my library in Mule application and added it to shared library. The custom library uses com.auth0.jwt package. I added it to mule-artifact.json in exportedPackages but still got error NoClassDefFoundError.

Error:

```
"Invocation of static Method 'main(java.lang.String[])' from Class 'com.mypackage.oauth.CustomAuth' with arguments [java.util.ArrayList<?> args] resulted in an error.\nExpected arguments are [java.lang.String[] args].\nCause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - com/auth0/jwt/JWT"
```

mule-artifact.json in my custom library:

```
{
  "minMuleVersion": "4.4.0",
  "classLoaderModelLoaderDescriptor": {
        "id": "mule",
        "attributes": {
            "exportedPackages": [
                "com.mypackage.oauth"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Custom library java class is using these import statements:

```
package com.mypackage.oauth;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
```

And I added it to my mule application in shared library of mule-plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bi-auth-utils</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
            <artifactId>bi-auth-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

I have already added jwt dependency in library pom.xml and imported xml file in the mule application to import the flows of mule library.

Comment: The information provided is completely insufficient for us to help you. Please provide complete error messages, the details in the pom (of the module and the Mule application), mule-artifact.json, code details, including the missing class and packages.

Comment: And please don't use MuleSoft (a company name) to refer to the Mule runtime.

Comment: @aled thank you for your helping feedbacks. I added mule-artifact.json and error message. And I imported the custom library as a dependency in mule application and added it as shared library. thank you

Comment: Please **do not** use images for text information like code and errors. The question is missing details of your custom library. You should provide enough information to reproduce the issue. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 8n detail.

Comment: @aled is it now good enough to answer ? If you can help

Comment: It is not yet fully clear. There are some strange things. More details are needed to clarify. How are you using this library in the flow? Why is the library dependency  a mule-plugin? Where is the dependency for the JWT library?

Comment: the library is used in the flow using an import configuration that imports xml file of the library. jwt dependency is already in pom.xml of the custom library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255914/discussion-between-ahmed-hmidi-and-aled).

Comment: You attempted to invoke the main method with an ArrayList of arguments when it should be a simple array.  That is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you @Aled and @Jim for your comments.

I fixed the issue by adding jwt library to the configuration of sharedLibrary in the Mule application:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bi-auth-utils</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
                            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you consider creating a Mule Module (ie a connector) using the [Mule Java SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/latest/getting-started) instead of calling this code directly. The reason is that a Module or Connector hides its dependencies from the application and simplifies the calling from a flow with a simple operation.